# Uploading large amounts of data via a csv into mysql Wordpress database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a large data set in Excel that I want to import into my mysql database for Wordpress.

The current data in Wordpress is made up of two important parts - the users and the posts (with custom data). Each is registered on the site (via the front end) and has to fill in some custom data about their company - that then creates a post and puts all the custom data into the custom fields.

I've used the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) to input the custom fields on a post.

How can I upload this list straight into the mysql database? It seems that the current data in Wordpress involves linking the user mysql table with the usermeta table and the posts with the post meta table... but all this seems to be in rows rather than columns, which would take a huge amount of work to reorder.

Isn't there an easier way?

If I have to do it in 3 stages then (1. the users. 2. the posts. 3. the post meta), then I'll have to do it that way. But surely there's a quicker more reliable solution!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few plugins that can do this for you, such as these:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-importer/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/

You'll need to set up a blank copy of WordPress, install the plugin, and go from there.

Comment: They don't handle the custom fields or users data. It purely handles posts and doesn't really cover what I need.

Comment: Here is one specifically for users:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-users-from-csv/

As for your custom fields, it really depends on what they contain.  Are these values from a different WP install or are they from some other site or structure?